# How to pass an environment variable to ExternalProject_Add CONFIGURE_COMMAND?

Tags: cmake, build-process, build-automation, autotools

I have a third party library with autotools project. I want to use ExternalProject_Add to build the library.

This can be done the following way:

```
ExternalProject_Add(project_lib
   SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib
   CONFIGURE_COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/configure --prefix=${LIB_OUTPUT}
   BINARY_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/build
)
```

Now the problem is that I need to pass an environment variable to `configure` but I cannot find a way to do it.

In the console I would do it the following way:

`CPPFLAGS="-fPIC" ./configure --prefix=output`

Is there a way to pass `CPPFLAGS="-fPIC"` env to the `configure` with `ExternalProject_Add/CONFIGURE_COMMAND` ?

Comment: Have you tried specifying the command the same way to `ExternalProject_Add()` as you do on the command line, environment variable and all?  If CMake spawns a shell to process the command, then it should work just the same (as opposed to if it launches the command directly).  The docs are unclear about which approach CMake uses.

Comment: Of course, if `CMake` does not automatically use a shell to run the command, then you can make it do so explicitly by making the command something like `/bin/sh -c 'CPPFLAGS="-fPIC" ./configure --prefix=output'`.  That is somewhat platform-specific, but `configure` isn't going to work without a version of the Bourne shell anyway.

Comment: Did you find a way? I'm having the same issue

Comment: @JonasVautherin Yes I did but completely forgot to mention it. I have to find it back in my  code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It can be done by executing `configure` command through cmake (`cmake --help`) [command mode](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/commit/7abd574798f9900abfe502f3941cffaa774062b1):

```
-E                           = CMake command mode.
```

So instead of calling `configure` directly we can execute it through cmake command mode with the environment variables:

```
ExternalProject_Add(project_lib
   SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib
   CONFIGURE_COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E env CPPFLAGS=-fPIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/configure --prefix=${LIB_OUTPUT}
   BINARY_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/build
)
```

*[[cmake-developers] Setting up environment using ExternalProject_Add](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake-developers/2015-August/025977.html)*

Comment: I'll try it tonight, but that would be amazing!

Comment: @Alexandre A. 
I cannot figure out how to make it work in my project which needs to export an environnement variable `ANDROID_NDK_rb16=path/to/ndk`.  

What do I have to add in the following to set this variable?  


`ExternalProject_Add(project_sqlite  

    URL urlToSqlite.zip  

    PREFIX ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/sqlite-${sqlite_VERSION}  

    CMAKE_ARGS -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=${CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE} -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE} -DCMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX=${CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX} -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=<INSTALL_DIR>
  )
`

Comment: @SteveTJS I'm not sure I understand. You can get env vars with `$ENV{ENV_NAME}`

Comment: @SteveTJS I expect it to work if following this answer. One thing with android projects is this answer probably won't work for windows hosts. I wonder if it's possible to handle both platforms..